# SAXParseException in Hibernate mapping

Tags: xml, hibernate

I want to generate class from hibernate mapping file by hbm2java, but I get the following error:

SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 15; The content of element type "class" must match "(meta*,subselect?,cache?,synchronize*,comment?,tuplizer*,(id|composite-id),discriminator?,natural-id?,(version|timestamp)?,(property|many-to-one|one-to-one|component|dynamic-component|properties|any|map|set|list|bag|idbag|array|primitive-array)*,((join*,subclass*)|joined-subclass*|union-subclass*),loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,filter*,fetch-profile*,resultset*,(query|sql-query)*)".

The content of mapping file is:

```
01    <?xml version="1.0"?>
02    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
03      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
04          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
05 
06    <hibernate-mapping package="test">
07 
08        <class name="phone" table="phone">
09                <property name="studentid" column="student_id" type="integer"/>
10                <property name="phone" column="number" type="string"/>          
11        </class>
12 
13    </hibernate-mapping>
```

- What I missed ?
- How can I interpret the error ? What are the: ?*
- Is there any free validator/editor which can help me to fill the xml ?

(Somehow eclipse doesnt show anything in the outline view ...)

Thanks in advance.

Cs

Comment: In the beginning there was an Id as well, but maybe then I had another error, I got this form by eliminations. So, I could find it out, if I focused on the part what has no * or ?. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` means: 0, 1 or more elements of the preceding type are expected.

`?` means 0 or 1 element of the preceding type is expected.

Nothing means exactly one of the preceding type is expected.

So you need an `id` or `composite-id` element (`(id|composite-id)`) before any `property` element.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the id property which is mandatory (on top of the two property elements):

```
<class name="phone" table="phone">
    <id column=...
```